# Why doesn't fillRect cover whole canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas tag without `width` and `height` attributes. The canvas has inline width and height. Now when I apply `linearGradient` over it, it doesn't cover whole canvas. Demo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



var gradient1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 150, 0);

gradient1.addColorStop(0, "#123456");
gradient1.addColorStop(1, "#654321");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient1;

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></canvas>
```

Question1: Why doesn't whole 150px of canvas get covered? And if I add `width="150"` and `height="100"` attributes on canvas tag, why does it then fill whole canvas?

Question 2: In below script `c.width` returns `300px` not `150px`, why?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


console.log(c.width);
console.log(c.height);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></canvas>
```

Question3: Is this behavior due to something similar to svg viewBox?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the inline styling isn't working, but if you change your canvas element to this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="150px" height= "100px;"></canvas>
```

Then the console logs the correct value and the gradient fills the canvas. :) I don't know why you can't use the other method, but I do know that everywhere I've seen I think everyone who uses the html canvas specifies the width and height in this way. (unless they specify it in the javascript)

Here's a pen of your working code: https://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/zwmmPY

Comment: Check the duplicate ;)

Comment: Yeah, duplicate's basically same thing. :P